# Best way to programmatically create dial images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, raphael

I'm working on a website that uses a lot of different sized and styled dials. These are used as progress indicators, so the more filled a dial is, the closer to 100% complete that item is.

I'm looking for a cross-browser, abstract solution so I can use the same solution across the different-styled dials. I'd use Google's Charts API, but unfortunately its dials don't offer the degree of customization needed. For an example, here are a handful of the images:

[image]

[image]

The functionality will be the same, but as you can see they're different dimensions.

I did try a solution with the Raphaël JavaScript library, but couldn't find a way to mask the complete image to show segments from 0 to 100%. The default image is grey, the complete image is the green ones you see above. I need to show values between 0 and 100.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raphaël doesn't do non-rectangular clipping AFAIK, even though SVG supports that.

This [clip-path animation](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/clippath/animated-clippath-arc.svg) might provide a bit of help for what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah, the non-rectangular clipping was what stumbled me when attempting to use it. What browser support does SVG have?

Comment: @MartinBean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#Support_for_SVG_in_web_browsers In short: Opera 8+, FF 3.0+, Safari and Chrome since 2006, and now IE9 all have native support.